# how to call the reporter task in grunt

Tags: gruntjs

This is my grunt file task,

```
mochaProtractor: {
  options: {
    configFile: 'conf.js',
    port: 9999,
    singleRun: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    logLevel: 'OFF'
  },
  files: ['test/Automative/*.js'],
  reporter:{
    reporter:'html_table_reporter'  ,
    outputFile: 'report/report.html',
    timeout: 60000
  }
}
```

not able to generate the report for my tests.